# integrate php login page to drupal

Tags: 6, hooks

I have a login page in php , I want to convert in drupal in the login page it directly access to the admin, is it possible? If its possible then what is the code for this to convert the user login in login page.

```
<td valign="top" class="rht_td">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><h3>SIGN IN</h3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>User Name : <span title="This field is required.">*</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="uname" class="wid100" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password: <span title="This field is required.">*</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" class="wid100" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Login" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table></form></td>
  </tr>
</table> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This isn't a 'give me the code' site; show the effort you've put into researching this question, and what you've tried so far, and people will be able to help

Comment: i didinot host the site. It is in localhost.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a 'give me the code' site? I'd like to go there!

Comment: @beth 10 years of searching and I still haven't found one!

Answer (score 1):

Integrating your login page with drupal is not as easy as copy pasting the code. Also creating a new module from scratch to attain your functionality is not worth your time, except as a learning exercise. You should be able to use existing, well-tested modules for what you're trying to do, although you may need to customize them from time to time to match your specific use case. Some modules that can help you in login are :

1. [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) - Redirect users to custom page after login based on their roles.
2. [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) - Provides a slick Twitter like login box and several other functionality.

These are very general suggestions but it sounds like you're in the very early stages of your planning; if you have specific questions, you're welcome to post those later.

Comment: I agree, and I would also add that a module that allowing to enter just the password would not be much useful, if not in a few cases, considering that different accounts can have the same password. Security is another factor too keep in mind; Drupal code is reviewed by many users, and it is difficult a single developer can provide more secure code.